# Whats the reverse of android:dependency

Tags: android, android-preferences

In Android if I wanted to only enable a CheckboxPreference when another certain CheckboxPreference is enabled, I would do something like this:

```
android:dependency="another_pref"
```

However, what if I want to do the reverse operation? Disable a preference when that certain is enabled. I cant seem to find any documentation on how to do that, yet Im pretty sure I once accomplished it somehow.

Thanks

Comment: Put the dependency on the other preference?

Comment: Dont think that would work, would it? Im not talking about toggling the checkBoxPreferences Im talking about disabling them (graying them out, making them unable to toggle)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to invert the intuition of the master checkbox, and then when it is checked, enable the other.

However, this does not answer your question. To do this, you have to execute the following code in your Preference Fragment/Activity's onSharedPreferenceChangedListener:

```
CheckBoxPreference masterPreference = (CheckBoxPreference) findPreference(key1);
Preference dependentPreference = findPreference(key2);
dependentPreference.setEnabled(!masterPreference.isChecked());
```

Code logic: this code takes the checked state of the master preference. If it is unchecked, the dependent preference is enabled, and vice-versa.